# Is there any specific reason why my code is not executing on all candles?

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v4

This is pretty simple

```
//@version=4
study("My script", overlay=true)


line ln = na
ln := line.new(bar_index, close, bar_index, close[10])
line.set_style(ln, line.style_dashed)
```

but this is the result I'm getting

[image: chart]

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong, s there any specific reason why my code is not executing on all candles?

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

There is a limit to the number of lines you can use on your chart. By default the limit is 50. You can extend this to 500 by using the max_lines_count parameter in study/strategy.

`study("My script", overlay = true, max_lines_count = 500)`

https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-reference/v4/#fun_study